predict function for glmmTMB
I have the following model:
mod <- glmmTMB(cound_data ~ year-1 +(1|Site), ziformula = ~year-1, data = df, family = "nbinom2"). I am modeling count data across 4 different years and 38 different sites. Due to the presence of many zeros in the data, I am using a zero-inflated model. My primary interest is in the effect of the years, but I am also interested in exploring the results for the different sites.
I obtained the fixed effects with the code: fixef(mod) and random effects with code: ranef(mod).
Let's say for the year 2018, I have a fixed effect of 0.85 and for Site "X" I have a random effect (intercept) of -0.18. From my understanding, to obtain the predicted value for Site "X" in 2018, I should calculate it manually as follows: exp(0.85-0.18)=1.95.
However, when I am using the predict() function: df$predicted_mean <- predict(mod, newdata = df, re.form = NULL, type = "response") I obtain a different value for Site "X" in 2018, such as 1.1. I don’t think this difference is due to rounding errors.
Does the predict() function calculate the values differently than my manual calculation? Does it account for the ziformula as well?

I don't know why, but my suspicion is that type = "response" is ignoring the random effect (this is what I have found from experiment). Try type = "link", and exponentiating that.

If this is about R, please use that tag.

tl;dr Your speculation that type = "response" includes the effect of zero-inflation is correct. Use type = "conditional" if you want to ignore it.
Reproducible example:
library(glmmTMB)
m <- glmmTMB(count ~ spp-1  + (1|site),
       zi=~spp-1,
       family=nbinom2, data=Salamanders)

From the documentation (?predict.glmmTMB):

"response": expected value; this is mu*(1-p) for zero-inflated models and mu otherwise

Let's look at the prediction for species PR in site R-1 (the first species, GP, has negligible zero-inflation). The parameters are [species PR] -1.1883 (conditional model); 0.03205 (zero-inflation model); [site R-1 random effect] 1.2903. So we should get
exp(-1.1883 + 1.2903)*(1-plogis(0.03205)) ## 0.5448

nd <- data.frame(spp = "PR", site = "R-1")
predict(m, newdata = nd, type = "response")  ## 0.5448

If you want to ignore the effect of zero-inflation, you should specify type = "conditional":
all.equal(exp(-1.1883 + 1.2903), predict(m, newdata = nd, type = "conditional"),
    tolerance = 1e-3)  ## TRUE

(I used a loose tolerance since I am rounding the coefficients to 5 significant digits).
If you want to ignore random effects, use re.form = NA.
?predict.glmmTMB gives more details.
